PostgreSQL error when editing PostGIS layer in Lizmap
I've installed lizmap web client 3.6.12 on a Debian 12.5 machine. I try to edit a layer via lizmap. I've installed PostGIS extension this way:
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS3UbuntuPGSQLApt

Exceptiong for ogr_fwd and postgis_sfcgal. this is the output of postgis_full_version():

POSTGIS="3.3.2 4975da8" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="150" GEOS="3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1" SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.4.1, CGAL 5.5.1, BOOST 1.74.0" PROJ="9.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02" LIBXML="2.9.14" LIBJSON="0.16" LIBPROTOBUF="1.4.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY RASTER

and this is the schema for the db:
schema_name     
--------------------
 postgis
 topology
 information_schema
 pg_catalog
 public

In QGIS I've exported a shapefile (points) into PostgreSQL(15) correctly and add it in a new PostGIS layer.
Now, when I try to edit a point in lizmap the loading bar keeps showing, doing nothing.
PostgreSQL log says:

qgis@qgis_test ERROR: function st_astext(postgis.geometry) does not exist at character 11

(qgis is the user, qgis_test is the db. qgis user have granted all to public and postgis)
when try to add a point:

invalid query (ERROR: function st_geomfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT GeometryType(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(359334.2646730018... ^ HINT: No functions found with the given name and argument types. You may need to convert the types explicitly.(SELECT GeometryType(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(359334.26467300183 4693797.256745067)', 32633)) as geomtype))

There are some other configuration for Lizmap to do?

have you tried this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308810/276 ?

@Mapperz In the link you suggested, it seems to me to be a connection problem. From my logs the connection it's ok, but lizmap doesn't seem to see the postgis extension, which is what QGIS does when I imported the shapefile

"qgis user have granted all to public and postgis" --> it also must have the postgis schema in its search path https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354523/use-postgis-functions-from-an-other-schema-than-public/354528#354528

@JGH this is the output of SHOW search_path: public, postgis, contrib, topology. entering psql with 'qgis' user
